# What is the correct response to a "does not"

Tags: negation

What is the correct response to the following question: "The purchase price of the property does not exceed £500,000" YES or NO.

The purchase price is £250,000 so less than £500,000. Would I select Yes or No?

Any help would be gratefully received.

Comment: I would tick 'Yes' as the statement is true.. I didn't think there could be any confusion until I saw the other answer!

Comment: I am sure this has been covered before but I cannot locate the duplicate. Apparently there are, indeed, two schools of thought. 'Yes, it does not' and 'No, it does not'.

Answer (score 1):

The sentence is a statement and the given statement is true. so the answer is YES.

Answer (score -1):

I'm totally not a native speaker but I would say that the correct option is "No, it doesn't". But from my experience you'll be understood anyway. However, I'm also interested to hear an opinion of native speakers!